# Emacs upgrade problem on Debian

Tags: debian, package-management, emacs

I am new to programming, Debian and emacs.

I tried to install packages of smex on emacs and I downloaded it from [smex@marmalade](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/smex) but when I do the install step, emacs told me there is no match for "package-install".

Then I thought I should upgrade my emacs23 to 24 but I can not upgrade to emacs24 by

```
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

and I also do not understand other ways to install smex without using "package-install".

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install `emacs24` explicitly, you should then be able to `M-x package-install`:

```
sudo aptitude install emacs24
```

On Wheezy (Debian 7), the simplest option to install Emacs 24 is to enable [backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude install -t wheezy-backports emacs24
```